# Azure Function App: Is it possble to not use KeyVaultSecret C# code in Function App?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I'm working on a function app and trying to use the key vault to store my connection string.

In my web MVC application we do not have to put in any C# code into place when we deploy to production.

In the web.config we just this line for our connection string:    `<connectionStrings configSource="connectionStrings.config" />` and it pulls all of the connection strings that are in the configuration section of our app service in Azure automatically.

**My Main question:**

Is it possible to do this in function app or do I have to directly put the C# code into pull from there based on connection string name?

Here is an example code that works with doing it via C#. I have to toggle the connection string name based on environment.

```
        public async Task<string> GetConnectionStringAsync(ILogger logger)
        {
            string connectionStringName = "DefaultConnectionFunction";
            string environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
            var connectionString = string.Empty;

            logger.LogInformation($"===> environment: {environment}");

            try
            {
                if (environment == "Production" || environment == "Test")
                {
                    var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
                    string apiUrl = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KeyVaultUrl");
                    var _client = new SecretClient(new Uri(apiUrl), credential);

                    if (environment == "Test")
                    {
                        connectionStringName = $"{connectionStringName}Test";
                    }

                    KeyVaultSecret secret = await _client.GetSecretAsync(connectionStringName);
                    connectionString = secret.Value;
                }
                else if (environment == "Development")
                {
                    string jsonFile = "local.settings.json";

                    IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                            .SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
                            .AddJsonFile(jsonFile)
                            .Build();

                    connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString(connectionStringName);
                }

                return connectionString;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle exceptions here.
                throw new ApplicationException($"Unable to retrieve the secret: {connectionStringName} from Azure Key Vault", ex);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I believe it's more idiomatic to have separate key vaults for test and prod, with the same key names in both. Regarding auto-loading, check out the key vault configuration provider.

Answer (score 0):

Do you run the Function App as a container or as a .NET Function App, Linux or Windows?

One option is to define the connection string as a "Application Setting" on the Function App that you can read out as a Environment Variable.

Also, if using Azure SQL, I would recommend looking into using Managed Identity to avoid secrets in the connection string.

Comment: I am doing it via .net Funtion app. I am using Managed Identity for the secrets, but Is there a way to do it like an MVC application, where you do not need any C# code to read it from the function app service config section? So my web.config doesn't have any connection strings declared and the appservice just injects it in for me. Curious if there is the same thing for a function app?

Answer (score 0):

> Azure Function App: Is it possble to not use KeyVaultSecret C# code in Function App?

Yes, you can use below way to get secret directly in local.settings.json, which after deployment will be stored in configuration section:

```
@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=keyvaultname;SecretName=secrename)
```

Firstly created secret as :

[image]

**`local.settings.json:`**

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "con": "@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=rithwik8;SecretName=connectionstring)"
  }
}
```

**`Function.cs:`**

```
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp70
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private readonly IConfiguration config;

        public Function1(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Function1>();
            config = configuration;
        }


        [Function("Function1")]
        public HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
        {


            string value = config.GetValue<string>("con");
            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

            response.WriteString("Hello Rithwik The connection string is :" + value);
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

**`Output:`**

[image]